# What is the purpose of "from __builtin__ import True"?

Tags: python, built-in

In some python code examples I see, `from __builtin__ import True`.

True is already built in, so i was wondering why should it be imported?

Comment: * from _ _ builtin _ _ import True

Comment: the purpose is to confuse people, including themselves, and to invoke the demons on this little planet, devouring all good open source code that exists, until there is none left that is pure, long live the evil warlord of bad code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no good reason, unless a module has, for some reason, overridden `True`, and you want the original value back:

```py
Python 2.7.15 (default, Feb 12 2019, 11:00:12)
>>> True = 8
>>> True
8
>>> from __builtin__ import True
>>> True
True
>>>
```

Also, `True`, `False` and `None` are keywords in Python 3, so this isn't possible in the first place.

```py
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36)
>>> True = 8
SyntaxError: can not assign to keyword
>>> from __builtin__ import True
    from __builtin__ import True
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    ^
```

Comment: The `__builtin__` module is called `builtins` in Python 3. Doesn't matter too much here, since there is still no `True` or `False` there to import, and `from builtins import  True` will still throw `SyntaxError`.